# Buscar resultado no banco de dados Mysql com o CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Preciso buscar um resultado no banco de dados, e mostrar na tela do carrinho.
Estou utilizando o codeigniter, já criei o model e o controller e estou chamando no view, mas o resultado não vem.

O valor que busco é 's' ou 'n' na tabela 'ga845_cliente' coluna 'atacadista'.

Agradeço o auxilio.

**Controller (carrinho)**

```
public function exibeAtacadista(){
    //busca os arquivo na tabela cliente
    $this->load->model('carrinho_model');
    $atacadista = $this->carrinho_model->getAtacadista($data);
    }
```

**Model (carrinho_model)**

```
public function getAtacadista($data){ 
        $this->db->flush_cache(); 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ga845_cliente` WHERE atacadista = 's' = ".$data['atacadista']." "; 
        $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
        print_r($query); die();
        return $query->result(); 
    }
```

**View (carrinho)**

Estou chamando assim.

```
echo 'teste:' .$atacadista;
```

Comment: A query retorna alguma lista? Se sim, poderia mostrar como vem os dados?

Comment: Não retorna nada, fica em branco, mas no banco tem o valor 's'

Comment: Eu uso uns comandos diferentes para fazer a busca na model, dá uma olhada e ve se te ajuda.
 `function getSetor($data) {
        $this->db->flush_cache();

        $sql = "
        SELECT u.id_setor, s.nome_setor FROM usuarios u
        LEFT JOIN setores s ON s.id_setor = u.id_setor
        WHERE u.id_usuarios = ".$data['id_usuario']."
        ";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }`

Comment: Pior que não deu também, como estou aprendendo a lidar com o codeigniter, ainda tenho dificuldades de entender onde pode estar o erro.

Comment: Tu testou a query no banco de dados?

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, estou no básico de PHP ainda, como faço isto?

Comment: O PHP roda em um servidor, geralmente o pessoal usa o phpAdmin do Xampp, seria esse?

Comment: Certo, isso mesmo

Comment: Acessando o phpAdmin, entra no teu banco de dados onde tem a `tabela ga845_cliente`, ao clicar nesta tabela, vai aparecer os dados. Acima dos dados tem umas abas, uma delas tem o nome de SQL, clica nela. Nesta parte, você cola o código  `SELECT * FROM `ga845_cliente` WHERE `atacadista ` = 'S'` e roda pra ver o resultado.

Comment: Certo, ele mostrou os dois resultados que eu tenho com o parâmetro 'S'

Comment: Blz, então , no teu controller tu precisa dar um `print_r($this->carrinho_model->getAtacadista($this->session->userdata('atacadista'));) die();`

Comment: E ver se printa no console do navegador(F12 - Network) a lista

Comment: Coloquei ele dentro do controller que eu mencionei acima, e ele não retornou nada no console

Comment: Eita... E se colocar o print_r no model? Ele retorna algo? Aonde tem `return $query` coloca `print_r($query); die();`

Comment: Também nada, pra ver se não estou fazendo errado, colei dentro do arquivo model depois da linha "return $query;"

Comment: Coloca esse comando antes do return, e ve se printa algo, pois não é possível que não vá printar....

Comment: Coloquei e também não mostrou nada, estou indo na minha página view que chama este model e controller, certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo, no teu view tu chama essa função e deveria printar algo no console... E a query tá correta, tanto que no banco de dados ela faz a busca e retorna... Como tá a tua configuração, no php, para conectar no banco? O caminho seria Application/config/database.php e ver a configuração na variavel $db[]

Comment: Pior que não chama nada, a configuração esta certa, pois ele busca os demais valores de outras tabelas. Como eu deveria chamar ela no view? So pra confirmar

Comment: Eu uso Ajax pra chamar, acho que não vai caber aqui no comentário, então criar uma resposta pra te mostrar.

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso AJAX para chamar as funções do controller pela view.

Mas no teu código,na Controller você está chamando `$this->carrinho_model->getAtacadista()` e na modal o nome da função está diferenta `public function getAtacado()` não deveria ser `public function getAtacadista()` ?

```php
function inserirProcesso() {
        var base_url = "<?php echo base_url() ?>"; // http://localhost/sistema/
            var data = $("#formInserirProcesso").serialize(); //Pega os dados dos input do form

            $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : base_url +'carrinho/exibeAtacadista',
                    data : data,
                    success :  function(response) {
                       alert('Confere se na console mostrou os dados');
                    }
            });
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Atualizei os códigos acima, conforme fomos falando, não entendi como chamar por AJAX, consegue ver se estou chamando a variável corretamente?